# Write error when trying to run unicorn: directory for pid=/var/www/twimpush/pids/unicorn.pid not writable (ArgumentError)

Tags: linux, nginx, file-permissions, unicorn

I've followed the steps in the DigitalOcean guides [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-2-1-0-and-sinatra-on-ubuntu-13-with-rvm) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-sinatra-based-ruby-web-applications-on-ubuntu-13) towards setting up a Sinatra server using nginx and Unicorn. I'm on the second to last step:

> start the Unicorn and run it as a daemon using the configuration file:
>   Make sure that you are inside the application directory
>   i.e. /my_app

```
unicorn -c unicorn.rb -D
```

Running that command, I get the error:

> directory for pid=/var/www/twimpush/pids/unicorn.pid not writable
>   (ArgumentError)

I've tried this as both `root`, and as a user called `deployer`, to which I gave write permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I cloned my git repo, it didn't include the empty `pids` folder inside my repo. I added it with `mkdir pids`, in addition to the other required folders mentioned in the first guide, and it worked.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so simple that I wasn't able to think about it. This error also could happen for logs dir